# Sort item in listbox by Alphabet?

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, windows-phone

**I use this function in my MainViewModel as the itemssource of my listbox...but i dont know how to sort them alphabetically. please help me**

```
 public void LoadData()
    {
        if (Data == null)
        {
            var oderedFullName = (from Member b in MemberDB.Members
                                 select b).OrderBy(b => b.FullName);
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Member>(oderedFullName);

        }

    }
```

**also tried this:**

```
 public void LoadData()
    {
        if (Data == null)
        {
            var oderedFullName = from Member b in MemberDB.Members
                                 orderby b.FullName
                                 select b;
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Member>(oderedFullName);

        }

    }
```

**and Load it in Show.xaml**

```
 public Show()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = App.MainViewModel;
        App.MainViewModel.LoadData();

    }
```

Comment: Noone can help me ?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the DataContext is set (`this.DataContext = App.MainViewModel;`), the member `Data` on `App.MainViewModel` is null, and will therefore not be bound. There are several ways to solve this, the simplest is to change the order to this:

```
public Show()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   App.MainViewModel.LoadData();
   this.DataContext = App.MainViewModel;
}
```

**Alternative solution**

Another solution is to make sure that Data is not null for example by setting it in the MainViewModel constructor like this:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    Data = new ObservableCollection<Member>();
}
```

And then do the following in LoadData:

```
public void LoadData()
{
   var orderedFullName = (from Member b in MemberDB.Members orderby b.FullName select b);
   Data.Clear();
   foreach (Member m in orderedFullName)
       Data.Add(m);
}
```

Also, for both solutions your XAML should look something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```